# OLE и VC++

Tags: ole, visual-studio, c++, visual-c++

Добрый день!
Столкнулся со следующей проблемой-Мне нужно подготовить отчет о работе программы в (*.doc) .

Пытался нарыть информацию-как воспользоваться ole сервером из под VC++.
Увы, но нашел только из под билдера.

Если кто сталкивался, скажите пожалуйста, где можно нарыть по этому информацию, а еще лучше покажите готовый пример работы!!

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: смотри что нашел 

http://habrahabr.ru/post/149277/

http://it.kgsu.ru/VC/vc_0170.html

а вообще [google + такой запрос][1]


  [1]: https://www.google.ru/search?q=ole+activex+msvs+c%2B%2B&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:ru:official&client=firefox-a#newwindow=1&client=firefox-a&hs=aIY&rls=org.mozilla:ru%3Aofficial&sclient=psy-ab&q=ole+activex+msvs+c%2B%2B+office&oq=ole+activex+msvs+c%2B%2B+office&gs_l=serp.3...183081.193953.1.194735.19.13.6.0.0.0.248.1558.2j10j1.13.0....0...1c.1.19.serp.iAxOVCPvKBc&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.48705608,d.bGE&fp=f3803bd44e99aff1&biw=1280&bih=821

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34998/MS-Office-OLE-Automation-Using-C

Comment: Готовый пример — это чересчур, а вообще-то вам нужно `CoInitialize` + `CoCreateInstance` + (`CComPtr` + `CComQIPtr` (ATL)) || (`AddRef`/`Release` +  `QueryInterface`) + `CoUninitialize`.